Intermittent WSTransport socket error with error code 31000 in Twilio
I'm working with Twilio and occasionally encountering a WSTransport socket error with error code 31000. This issue seems to happen intermittently, and refreshing the page usually resolves it. Here are the details:
**Twilio Service: Voice
Error Message: WSTransport socket error - code 31000
Frequency: Occurs sporadically; refreshing the page often resolves the issue.**

`

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Device } from 'twilio-client';

function App() {
    const [device, setDevice] = useState(null);
    const [callStatus, setCallStatus] = useState('idle');

    const handleButtonClick = async () => {
        try {
            const tokenResponse = await axios.get('localhost:3001/fetchtoken');
            const token = tokenResponse.data.token;

            const newDevice = new Device(token, { 
                debug: true,
                audioConstraints: {
                    optional: [
                        { echoCancellation: true },
                        { noiseSuppression: true },
                        { autoGainControl: true }
                    ]
                }
            });

            newDevice.on('ready', () => console.log('Device ready'));
            newDevice.on('error', error => console.error('Device error:', error));
            newDevice.on('connect', () => setCallStatus('connected'));
            newDevice.on('disconnect', () => setCallStatus('idle'));

            setDevice(newDevice);

            newDevice.connect({ From: "test" });

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    };

    const disconnectCall = () => {
        if (device) {
            device.disconnectAll();
            setCallStatus('idle');
            console.log('Call disconnected');
        } else {
            console.error('Twilio device is not initialized');
        }
    };

What exactly does error code 31000 signify in the context of Twilio's WSTransport socket errors?
Are there known issues or best practices to mitigate this intermittent connectivity issue?
Could there be a configuration or timeout setting that I might be overlooking?

Any insights or suggestions to help resolve or further troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.
